# Python file in a Docker container does not recognise path to packages in imports

Tags: python, docker

I have a small Python airflow application which is copied into a Docker container running airflow, with the following declaration:

```
volumes:
  - ~/Path/To/My/App/my-app-repo/dags/my_app:/usr/local/airflow/dags/my_app/
```

Location `/Path/To/My/App/my-app-repo/dags/`contains the following structure. Names without file extension are folders.

```
my_app
  __init__.py
  my_app.py
  extensions
    __init__.py
    utility_methods/
      __init__.py
      some_file_with_defs.py
```

`some_file_with_defs.py` contains def `foo(bar)`

at `my_app.py` I call the following import

`from extensions.utility_methods.some_file_with_defs import foo`

But in Airflow UI, I get the following error:

```
Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/my_app/my_app.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/my_app/my_app.py", line 15, in <module>
    from extensions.utility_methods.some_file_with_defs import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'extensions'
```

Playing around with the paths (like adding a `.` before extensions, or writing `dags.my_app.utility_methods.some_file_with_defs` results in the same type of error.

`Workdir` of the Dockerfile is set at `/usr/local/airflow/`

Is there something I'm missing? It seems that Docker is manipulating the folder structure, or that Python is unable to find the path for some reason.